# I can't find the record button

Tags: animation, interface

I imported a model and am looking through Blender right now, but I can't seem to animate that model. How would I do so? I can't seem to find the animate option. I used to be able to see the Record button in the options. Normally the option doesn't show up.

I was following a tutorial on how to animate a model and I got stuck. Here is a screenshot of what my screen looks like now:

[image: screenshot 1]

In the menu visible in the image, there is usually a record button, but I can't find it now.

This is what I mean by the Record option (see the sequence of buttons in the centre above the Timeline):

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: No offence but these tools seem poorly designed and needlessly complex.

Comment: What do you mean by 'animate option'? - In Blender, you animate objects by setting a keyframe for each movement with the 'I' (insert keyframe) key. The record button you're talking about is probably the one you see at the top of theTimeline for auto-keyframing, but you currently have the Acrtion Editor open. If you're new to Blender I'd suggest you look at a few of the many Blender YT animation tutorials that are online.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk7Yq.jpg in this menu there is usually a record button. But i don't see the option. That's my question. I had an image but it got edited out by an admin. This is what i mean by the record option: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPDRk.jpg

Comment: The blue and white button in the centre shows that you have autokeying turned on already which I assume is what you mean by the record button. If you move your object and move to another frame the keyframe will automatically have been set on the frame you've moved from.

Comment: Incidentally the only window with a record button on it in Blender is the Timeline (your second image). The Action Editor (your top image) doesn't have a record button.

Comment: Somewhere in the tutorial, they should have told you that to animate a rig you need to be in _Pose_ model.  In the upper right of the 3d Viewport you can see a drop down menu that says "Object Mode".  For now, click that word and select "Pose Mode" from the menu that appears.  You should be able to continue following the tutorial at that point.

Comment: just open another workspace window and choose *Timeline* as editor type then you have the autokeying and the other buttons again. (https://youtu.be/HSm-cq7zd2s)

Comment: @Ilda There are many questions here that would help you find the "Record" (properly called auto keyframe) button.

Answer (score 2):

You don't see the **RECORD** button because you are in the **DOPE SHEET** Editor.

You need to change the Editor from **Dope Sheet** to **Timeline**.

Hope this helps :)